Under part 103.7 how much more can an all composite amphibian weigh rather than 254 lbs since it already has a boat monocoque hull and sponsons?
Under part 103.7 how much more can an all composite amphibian weigh  rather than 254 lbs since it already has a boat monocoque hull and sponsons?
